# How to tackle "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-http

I have written a service for an API call to fetch the data. Below is my service code.

```
  export class SurveyServiceService {

  private surveysUrl = 
  'http://107.170.59.79/services/public/api/v1/countries';
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getSurveys(): Promise<Survey[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.surveysUrl)
       .toPromise()
       .then(response => response.json() as Survey[])
       .catch(this.handleError);
  }
 }
```

Below is my component for getSurveys function

```
export class SurveysComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Survey List';
  surveys: Survey[];
  keys: String[];
  selectedSurvey: Survey;

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private surveyService: SurveyServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getSurveys();
    this.keys = Object.keys(this.surveys);
  }

  getSurveys(): void {
    this.surveyService.getSurveys().then(surveys => this.surveys = surveys);
  }
 }
```

Since I am getting data in json object I tried to convert into array by using below code, so that I can iterate it using *ngFor in the HTML.

```
this.keys = Object.keys(this.surveys);
```

But when I run the code I receive an error as

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Can someone please let me know where I went wrong?

Comment: Http uses AJAX requests. The A means Asynchronous. The whole point of a promise is to represent the future result of an asynchronous operation. getSurveys() **sends** a request, then returns immediately. The surveys are only available later, when the callback function passed to then() has been executed. Put that `this.keys = Object.keys(this.surveys);` line **inside** the callback passed to then().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JB Nizet's comment is right solution, I put answer here for clear code.

```
export class SurveysComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Survey List';
  surveys: Survey[];
  keys: String[];
  selectedSurvey: Survey;

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private surveyService: SurveyServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getSurveys().then(surveys => {
       this.surveys = surveys;
       this.keys = Object.keys(this.surveys);
    });
  }

  getSurveys(){
    return this.surveyService.getSurveys();
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use a pipe but I had the same issue you faced.
Instead, I use this as a workaround.

```
.subscribe(
    res =>
    {
    this.apiarray = []; <--- Empty array here
    console.log("response form api :  " + JSON.stringify(res));
    this.ResultfromApi= res;
    this.apiarray.push(this.PatientInfoFromApi);
    }
```

Now you just iterate over the array instead of the object. In the template,
Your *ngFor loop goes like this

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of apiarray">
  <td>{{item.specific_key_to_your_result}}</td>
  ...
</tr>
```